# How to create own custom date picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Hi guys i want How to create own custom date picker using flutter.

i share my UI concept : [View UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2gzE.png).

No.1 : Display current year future 5 month on top header.
No.2 : click any month on top header to change calender on clicked month.
No.3 : clickable date calender.

[see UI design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2gzE.png)

Any one pls share the flutter code.

Comment: "Any one pls share the flutter code." what's your code then? what have you done so far?

Comment: i completed dialog box only, i want custom date picker code logic, this UI https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2gzE.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Syncfusion_flutter_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar) to achieve this functionality. This plugin provide wide range of calendar feature with customisation option.

Comment: You should avoid Syncfusion packages if possible. Check their [License](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar/license).